# To fetch database objects and data for other DB than default

Tags: java, database, sap-ase

We are working on `Sybase` database using Java JDBC. We are fetching some data and data objects from Sybase. Below code is used to get data :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(sDBUrl, sUserName, sPassword);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);
```

`DriverManager.getConnection` create and get connection for database url, user name and password given. Database Url format is : **192.123.111.15:5000?ServiceName=DATABASENAME**

BUT there is no effect of database name given in `getConnection`, it always return database objects and its data for DEFAULT database set for the user.

**What we need is** : We need to get database objects and data from database name specified in DB url NOT default one.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using ?

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/X32549.htm

Comment: @MichaelGardner thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to put your solution down as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Sure